# Getting a using a non static variable in a static class error with a linked list

Tags: java, list

The is a homework assignment in which I need to write a psuedo facebook app.  The only constraints are that I need to use a collection to hold the friends and the people I create  - I can choose which ones - and that the people class must contain a construct for the friends and for the  person. And this is where I am running into trouble.  I keep getting an error "you can't use a non static variable in a static class" so I have tried making it static, making it a construct calling it through another variable - you name it no go (honestly I would never have done it this was unless it was homework - this is a sql code waiting to happen)

here is my code

```
              mport java.util.LinkedList;


    public class person {

        private String name;
        public  static String nameIn;


      LinkedList<String> friends = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void addFriends(friends){

        this.friends= friends;

    public static void setNameIn(String nameIn) {
        person.nameIn = nameIn;
    }

    public static String getNameIn() {

        return nameIn;
    }

    public void name (String nameIn){
       this.name = nameIn;

    }

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class A05 extends person {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean success;
        String userData;
        System.out.println("please enter command");
   String userCommand;
   Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   userInput.useDelimiter( "' ");
   userCommand = userInput.nextLine();




   switch (userCommand) {
       case ("p"): {
           System.out.println("Please the name of the new user");

           Scanner userString = new Scanner(System.in);
           userString.useDelimiter("' ");
           userData = userString.nextLine();
          .nameIn.set(userData);
           success = true;
           System.out.println("New user added Successfully");
       }
       break;
       case ("f"): {


           System.out.println("Please enter the new friend and then the user's name seperated by a space");
           Scanner userString = new Scanner(System.in);
           userString.useDelimiter("' ");
           userData = userString.nextLine();
             person.addFriends.friends.add(userData);
           success = true;
            return success;
           System.out.println("Friend has been added successfully");
       }
       break;
       case ("u"): {

           System.out.println("Please enter data");
           Scanner userString = new Scanner(System.in);
           userString.useDelimiter("' ");
           userData = userString.nextLine();
           person.addFriends.friends.remove(userData);
           success = true;
           return success;
           System.out.println("friend has been removed successfully");
       }
       case ("l"): {
           System.out.println("please enter the name of the person whose friends you wish to list");
           Scanner userString = new Scanner(System.in);
           userString.useDelimiter("' ");
           userData = userString.nextLine();

       }
   }


           TreeMap<String, LinkedList> personMap = new TreeMap<String, LinkedList>();

                         personMap.put(person.nameIn, person.friends);




        }


}
```

Comment: You're not creating an instance of `person`.

Comment: I don't think the `A05` should extend `person` (N.B., by convention classes in Java start with an upper case). The `public void addFriends(friends)` won't compile as it is missing the type of the parameter. I'm not sure why you are using a static for the `nameIn` (that means every instance of the `person` class will have the same value). And the code is missing some closing braces.

Comment: A05 extended person so it could inheret the person object - but your right it does not need to do so.  I took the addFriends class out (it was my attempt to put friends in a static class which did not work.

Comment: `addFriends` isn't a class, it's a method. There is no reason to create a new `Scanner` every time you want to read input.